# Estimating mortality rates when $n_t=0$

Tags: calculus, estimation

I am using a series of observations to calculate mortality rates:

$m=1-(n_t/n_0)^{1/t}$

$n_0$ number of individuals in the first observation

$n_t$ number of individuals at time $t$

I am comparing mortality rates for among different species of plants. I have the information of $n_0$ and $t$ when $n_t = 0$. Therefore for all species $m$ will be $1$ using the available information.

However, I know that mortality rates are not the same among the species, because for each species I have a different $t$ where $n_t = 0$.

Do you have any suggestions on how to estimate $m$ using this data?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you get more data, e.g., the number of individuals at some other time?

Comment: No, unfortunately this is the only information I have available.

Comment: The equation can be transformed into $n_t=n_0(1-m)^t$. It is an exponential decay curve. You can see $n_t$ goes to zero but does not reach zero. So the equation only gives you an approximation of the point where $n_t=0$. That makes it hard to use your information to estimate $m$.

Comment: I understand that. The experiment starts with 40 individuals per species. I have the information for each species when all individuals are dead. For example, species A, 22 days; species B, 26 days... So I know that they have different mortality rates, but I cannot calculate a value of mortality rate.